# How can I correctly override Express method with strict args types?

Tags: typescript, express

I want to set restrictions on a data, that can be passed to express' `res.send()`.
For now I have following type declarations:

```
interface ServerResponseData {
  data?: object | object[];
  errors: string[];
}

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  interface Request {
    user?: {
      isAdmin: boolean;
      token: string;
    };
  }

  interface Response {
    /**
     * Overridden Express.Response method.
     * Sends only strictly typed data.
     * @param {string} body.text Short description of request results.
     * @param {object} [body.data] Data to send.
     */
    send(body: ServerResponseData): Response;
  }
}
```

It does work for overriding `Request`, but not for Response. TSlint says that `send` is already declared. In route handler it uses 'old' typings, without given restrictions.

What should I do to get this to work?
Thanks.